# how do I fix this error with async functions `sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'finish_process' was never awaited`

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

The goal of this code is to make it run the main function, called `main_process()`, until the async function of ending, called `finish_process()`, sets the variable `finish_state` to `True` and the loop doesn't repeat itself.

```py
import asyncio
import time

condition = True
finish_state = False
x = 0

async def finish_process(finish_state):
    finish_state = True
    time.sleep(5)
    return finish_state

async def main_process(condition,finish_state,x):
    while condition == True:
        finish_state = await asyncio.run(finish_process(finish_state))
        
        x = x + 1
        print(x)

        #if(x > 10):
        if(finish_state == True):
            print("Termina!")
            condition = False


asyncio.run(main_process(condition,finish_state,x))
```

I have already put the await to the asynchronous function call inside another asynchronous function, I don't understand why it keeps giving the error with the `await`.

I thought that indicating with `await` or with the old `yield from` should fix the simultaneous waiting for the results of the other function.

```
raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'finish_process' was never awaited
```

Comment: from the official [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=asyncio.run#asyncio.run) on `asyncio.run`: "This function cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is running in the same thread."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has the following issues：

1. You should use [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) or [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) to run asynchronous tasks, not [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run).
2. Can replace `time.sleep(5)` with `await asyncio.sleep(5)`

```py
import asyncio
import time

condition = True
finish_state = False
x = 0

async def finish_process(finish_state):
    finish_state = True
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return finish_state

async def main_process(condition,finish_state,x):
    while condition == True:
        finish_state = await asyncio.create_task(finish_process(finish_state))
        
        x = x + 1
        print(x)

        #if(x > 10):
        if(finish_state == True):
            print("Termina!")
            condition = False


asyncio.run(main_process(condition,finish_state,x))
```

Output:

```
1
Termina!
```

Comment: Do you really mean to have both a global variable named `finish_state` that's never modified, but two local variables?

Comment: @FrankYellin It is used here (`asyncio.run(main_process(condition,finish_state,x))`), but inside the function there is a local variable with the same name.

Comment: Okay.   It looked a little bit weird.  And it's a common error to confuse local variables and global variables.  But you clearly know what you're doing.

Comment: @FrankYellin yeah, i just fixed the problem.